# Qt TCP/IP socket connection check

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp

I am writing Qt TCP/IP client. I want to check the connection state with server before send data to sever. 
As far my knowledge I can do this by following methods

- Use a bool '*ConnectionState*', set this variable when connected with
  sever and reset this variable on *disconnected()* signal. Now before
  sending data to server (client->write()) check the value of this
  variable.
- use this '*client->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState*' way to check the connection state.

Which is good practice. Or any other method to this.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: One possible approach is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10447560/514235). But that's not Qt way. @beparas, did creating a slot for `error(SocketError)` signal work for you. For me it's not working as described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`QTCPSocket` is derived from `QAbstractSocket`, which provides a `state()` function. This returns one of the following enums: -

```
enum SocketState { UnconnectedState, HostLookupState, ConnectingState, ConnectedState, ..., ListeningState }
```

So, assuming m_pSocket is a `QTcpSocket`, you would simply do this to check if it is connected:-

```
bool connected = (m_pSocket->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState);
```

You could add a boolean and keep track of the state, but if a network error occurs you need to ensure that it is always in-sync with the actual connection state.

Comment: Connect a slot to the error signal: void error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)

Comment: I have connected a slot to the `error(SocketError)` signal, but that is never invoked even when the Wifi is switched off. Following statements doesn't have any effect on this: `setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, true)` and `setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, true)`.  Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: @iammilind, I suggest asking this as a separate question on SO, with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Qt: Why is `QAbstractSocket::error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)` signal not generated when internet is disconnected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44803126/514235)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `errorOccurred` signal and It's just enough for this signal define a slot in client. when an error occurs, a signal trigger and you can receive notify in slot function.

In client.h

```cpp
/* define a slot for client */
public slots:
    void errorOccurred(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error);
```

In client.c

```cpp
/*client constructor*/
Client::Client(QObject *parent) {
/*some other code here*/
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(errorOccurred(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
        this, SLOT(errorOccurred(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

/*and maybe some other code here*/
}
```

and in client.c write implementation for errorOccurred:

```cpp
void Client::errorOccurred(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error) {
    qDebug() << "error in connection: " << socket->errorString();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
error in connection:  "Connection refused"
```